# Extracting Source => Destination rx / tx from procfs (/proc)

Tags: networking, tcp, connection, network-traffic, proc

I know I can get rx and tx bytes for each NIC from /proc/..., but I'm looking to get rx and tx info for each source => destination pair -- basically traffic info for each network connection.

In /proc/net/tcp and /proc/net/tcp6 I see local_address and rem_address, but I don't see the rx and tx info.  Other procfs files I've seen have rx and tx info, but only per NIC.

Are there any procfs files that would help me get the rx/tx info for each network connection?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`iftop` will show you bandwidth usage on an interface by host in a continuous updating display.

It is packet capture based, so is not a procfs thing. However this means it has a chance to be portable and work on OSes in addition to Linux.